# why we use local file settings when initalizing celery app

Tags: django, celery

Most of the places i see

```
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings.local') --> ??

app = Celery('mysite')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

what is the use of exporting local settings in project, i have seen this in many projects in production we are using local settings, although local mostly inherit base settings where all celery config is defined, by why not mysite.settings.production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.environ.setdefault will first look to content of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable if not found set it to default value

You don't want to have hassle of setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable on every development machine, but in production you will set this variable to production config.